# Reading from unbuffered os.fdopen() file object doesn't behave like os.read()

Tags: python, file-descriptor

I have the following code

```
r, w = os.pipe()
rf, wf = os.fdopen(r, 'rb', 0), os.fdopen(w, 'wb', 0)
wf.write('hello')
```

When reading it with

```
rf.read(10)
```

It blocks forever. However, if I'm reading it with

```
os.read(r, 10)
```

It returns `'hello'` without waiting for 10 bytes to be available.

Question is: How do I make `.read()` on `os.fdopen()`'ed file object behave the same? (aka non-blocking)

Comment: It doesn’t block in Python 3, interestingly enough.

Comment: That is intentional. `file.read` [tries to read the exact number of bytes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file.read#file.read). Python 3 differentiates between buffered and unbuffered i/o and has [an additional `read1` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase.read1) that does not call `read` more than once.

Comment: @Phillip this looks like the right direction. Any idea how to achieve the same behavior with Python2? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know of any way (but I'm not sure none exists, hence I won't post this as an answer). But you can work around the issue by using `io.open(r, 'rb').read1(10)`, `select` on a non-blocking file, or simply stick with `os.read`.

Comment: @Phillip Python2 doesn't have `.read1()`, however, using `io.open(r, 'rb', 0)` works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by using `io.open()` instead of `os.fdopen()`

Note that you must use `buffering=0` for this to work:

```
rf = io.open(r, 'rb', 0)
rf.read(10)
```

Answer (score 3):

There might be a better way, but you can use the [`fcntl` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) to set `O_NONBLOCK`:

```
import fcntl

r, w = os.pipe()
fcntl.fcntl(r, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
…
```

Comment: This only is a partial answer. `rf.read` and `os.read` will show the same behaviour afterwards, but `os.read` won't behave as before. (It will raise an IOError if there is no data available, instead of blocking.)

Comment: Thanks. Apparently `file.read()` keeps calling `os.read()` until the buffer fills (like @Phillip said). Changing the file to non-blocking mode solves this by making `os.read()` raise an exception when there aren't any bytes left in the OS buffer.

Comment: @Phillip actually I don't need `os.read()` to keep working. I wanted `os.fdopen()` to behave as I requested

Comment: Ok. There is a problem with this method. It makes `file.read()` non-blocking (obviously) when there is no data in the OS buffer (unlike `os.read()`).

Comment: this should be the answer! I'm on Python 3.5 and by defaults it blocks, rf, wf = os.fdopen(r, 'rb', 0); rf.read(123) blocks without fcntl it first.